# Highcharts suddenly shows less points

Tags: highcharts

Up until now, my highcharts was working fine. I have about 7,300 data points and new data is added once every hour.

Before, when I first loaded the highchart, it loaded and displayed all of the data normally (each point was 1 hour apart).

Today, I noticed that it only displays a point until it's 12 hours apart unless you zoom in. Is there a setting in highcharts that filters how many points can be shown or something?

Comment: Have you tried increase value of [turboThreshold](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold) parameter.

Comment: I would also check if dataGrouping settings are to blame: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping

Comment: Changing turboThreshold didn't work. I use `plotOptions: { series: { turboThreshold: 100000 } }`